# Trying to filter php table and show phone specs from PHP table

Tags: php, php-5.1

I am currently new to PHP and I am working on a project that allows the customer to filter the phone brands they want and select from the phone PHP table they want to choose. I am running into multiple errors with this project, one is that my phones.php does not show the specific phone that the customer wants to choose and I cannot seem to find a way to filter the PHP table as well as import the .CSV file into the PHP table.

Below is my code
test.php (page you land on)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <label for="manufacturer">Package Type: </label>
    <select id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Google">Google</option>
        <option value="OnePlus">OnePlus</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

All Phones Test 
<table border=1>
<th>Item</th><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Model</th><th>Price</th></th>

Table below is for reference
v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v 
All Phones
<table border=1>
    <th>Item</th><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Model</th><th>Price</th></th>
    <form action="phones.php" method="post"><tr><td>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="0" value="0"</td><td>Samsung</td>
        <td>Galaxy S20</td><td style="text-align:right">$       1199.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="b" id="1" value="1"</td><td>Apple</td>
        <td>iPhone 11</td><td style="text-align:right">$        699.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="c" id="2" value="2"</td><td>Samsung</td>
        <td>Galaxy Note 20 Ultra</td><td style="text-align:right">$       1099.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="c" id="3" value="3"</td><td>Apple</td>
        <td>iPhone 11 Pro</td><td style="text-align:right">$       1099.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name= "d" id="4" value="4"</td><td>OnePlus</td>
        <td>OnePlus 8 Pro</td><td style="text-align:right">$        899.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="e" id="5" value="5"</td><td>Apple</td>
        <td>iPhone SE 2020</td><td style="text-align:right">$        399.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="g" id="6" value="6"</td><td>Samsung</td>
        <td>Galaxy S20 Ultra</td><td style="text-align:right">$       1399.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="h" id="7" value="7"</td><td>Samsung</td>
        <td>Galaxy S10</td><td style="text-align:right">$        849.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="i" id="8" value="8"</td><td>OnePlus</td>
        <td>OnePlus 7 Pro</td><td style="text-align:right">$        549.00</td></tr><tr><td><input type="radio" name="j" id="9" value="9"</td><td>Google</td>
        <td>Pixel 4 XL</td><td style="text-align:right">$        499.00</td></tr></table>
        <input type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

phones.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

function  CalcTax($fltamt){
    $fltTax = 0.0;
    $fltTaxRate = 0.00;
    $fltTax = $fltAmt * $fltTaxRate;

    return $fltTax;
}

function Calculate Cost($strPhone){
    $fltTax = 0.0;
    $fltPrice = 0.0;
    $fltTotal = 0.0;

    if ($strPhone == "a") {$fltPrice = 1199.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "b") {$fltPrice = 699.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "c") {$fltPrice = 1099.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "d") {$fltPrice = 1099.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "e") {$fltPrice = 899.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "f") {$fltPrice = 399.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "g") {$fltPrice = 1399.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "h") {$fltPrice = 849.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "i") {$fltPrice = 549.00};
    elseif ($strPhone == "j") {$fltPrice = 499.00};
    
    $fltTotal = $fltPrice + CalcTax($fltPrice);

    echo "Total Price of Phone: $".number_format($fltTotal,2,".",",")."<br>\n";

}

$pkgType = $_POST["package"];

if ($pkgType == "a") {echo "Samsung Galaxy S20\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "b") {echo "Apple Iphone 11\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "c") {echo "Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "d") {echo "Apple Iphone 11 Pro\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "e") {echo "OnePlus 8 Pro\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "f") {echo "Apple Iphone SE 2020\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "g") {echo "Galaxy S20 Ultra\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "h") {echo "Samsung Galaxy S10\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "i") {echo "OnePlus 7 Pro\n";}
elseif ($pkgType == "j") {echo "Pixel 4 XL\n";}
CalculateCost($pkgType);


}
echo "You have chosen the ".$pkgType. "<br>";
}
}
   
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

CSV file:

[image]

Comment: Function `Calculate Cost` seems to have a space in the name? ... check the webserver error_log for potential clues with (errors/notices/warnings) if there seems to be trouble.

Comment: @PaulT. Fixed! But Im still loading a blank page

Comment: Yes, that is why to check the error_log. You could also add to the top of the script: (after the opening php tag) `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` The blank screen typically implies a `PHP Fatal` error.

Comment: Also, another thing you can do, from the command line, is run `php -l file.php` to check for syntax errors.

Comment: Inside function `CalculateCost`, move all the `;` that appears at the end of the `if` and all the `elseif` lines to just inside the closing `}` on each line.

Comment: ...and down around the last `echo`, appears to be 3 stray `}` closing braces. These may simply need to be removed, as there appears to be no opening `{` to match these?

Comment: remove semicolon in your calculatecost else if statement

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, I did what you guys said to do but nothing is working.